# Style Drupal 7 log-in page

Tags: drupal, authentication, drupal-7, drupal-theming

How do I style the login-page of Drupal 7? I used different methods like `page-user-login.tpl` or `user-login.tpl` of `page-login.tpl` but with no results.

Is there an easy way to theme your login page in Drupal 7 in his own `.tpl`-file?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can override any page template by naming your templates in the following convention:

For page 'user/login':

```
page--user--login.tpl.php
```

For page 'foo/bar/'

```
page--foo--bar.tpl.php
```

See [Core templates](http://drupal.org/node/190815) and [About overriding themable output](http://drupal.org/node/173880) for more information.

Remember to clear Drupal's caches once you add a new template file so the theme registry has a chance to pick the new file up.

Comment: Got it, thanks!! A `page--user.tpl.php` is required though. And it's only working with `page--user--login.tpl.php`! But thanks!

Comment: @Michiel: Sorry, I left out a dash, I've updated that in the answer. Check out [this link](http://drupal.org/node/1089656) as well it's the one I was originally looking for and explains all this very well

Comment: Thanks for the additional link

Comment: @Clive Thank you so much for the gerat help.