# Style Drupal 7 log-in page (with hook_prepare/hook_preprocess)

Tags: drupal-7, hook

Despite a  [previous solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8712061/style-drupal-7-log-in-page) to my own question, I'm not completely satisfied. I now have three exactly the same pages (`page.tpl.php`, `page--user.tpl.php` and `page--user--login.tpl.php`) with only a slight difference in the last page. So if I have to edit a single div for some reason, I have to change it in all three pages.

So I'm looking for a more solid solution (it will probably be in the `template.tpl`-file with a `hook_prepare`/`hook_preprocess`. But I have no idea how to do this... Can anyone provide me with some hints or info?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not the better solution for me but you can use the `arg()` function in your `page.tpl.php` like this :

```
if (arg(0) == 'user') {
  // Do something
  if (arg(1) == 'login') {
    // Do something else
  }
}
```

Depending on your needs you may also customize your pages using only CSS rules as body tag carry some usefull classes.